# Android Play video in Mediaplayer?

Tags: android

Video in res->raw folder.I want to play video directly in mediaplayer.I trying to search in  google but cant get final solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't tested yet, but I think this should work,
Tell me if you found and issue.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/"+videoName);
Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```